# How to fix errors in Sharepoint search (no refiners found)

Tags: 2013, search, form, refiner

SharePoint version: 2013 (not office 365 )

I have a SharePoint site that I built about a month ago.  I am the administrator of the site.  The sites function is to track changes to remote sites in our area.  When I first began using the site, I could go to the top right of the page and enter the six digit site number (which is populated in the list for each and every row) and the search page would return the results.  The results usually has three results and one of those would display the information for the selected row and bring up a page that would show every columns information associate with that row.

Last week a user of the site let me know that it (the search function) was no longer working.  The user was unable to come up with anything that they did prior to the search function becoming broken.

Now when you run a search on the top right of the screen, I get the following message:

***We don't have any refiners to show you***

I need help in identifying how the search function became corrupted and how to fix it.  I have too much data in this list to simply create a new one.

Here is what I have tried or verified so far:

> Site Settings> Search> Search Settings -- use the same results page settings as my parent.
>
> Site Settings> Site Collection Administration> Search Settings-- use the same results page settings as my parent.
>
> List>List Settings>Advanced settings -- Allow management of content types
>
> List>List Settings>Advanced settings -- Allow items from this list to appear in search results
>
> List>List settings>Advanced settings -- reindex list (waited over period of three days)
>
> List>Form Web Parts> Default new form
>
> List>Form Web Parts> Default Display Form
>
> List>Form Web Parts> Default Edit Form

I have tried to save the site (list) as a template and import it as a new web app.  However, the template does not show up under my apps or "apps that you can add"

I have tried to import the list as a spreadsheet but I get an error and excel crashes.

Any and all advice would be helpful